# Let $F(x)=\int_0^x\left(t\int_1^tf(u)\,du\right)\,dt$. Show that $F''(x)$ is increasing on $(0, 1)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity

Question:

> Suppose that $f(x)$ is continuous and increasing on $[-1, 2]$ with $f(x)>0$. Let $F(x)=\int_0^x\left(t\int_1^tf(u)\,du\right)\,dt$. Show that $F''(x)$ is increasing on $(0, 1)$.

This is an exercise about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Below is my attempt.

My idea is to show that $F'''(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in(0, 1)$.

$$\begin{align}F(x)=\int_0^x\left(t\int_1^tf(u)\,du\right)\,dt&\implies F'(x)=x\int_1^xf(u)\,du\\
&\implies F''(x)=\int_1^xf(u)\,du+xf(x)\\
&\implies F'''(x)=2f(x)+xf'(x)
\end{align}$$

Here I want to say that $f'(x)\geq0$ for all $x\in(0, 1)$ since $f(x)$ is increasing on $(0, 1)$. However, I am not sure whether $f'(x)$ exists for all $x\in(0, 1)$. The question only states that $f(x)$ is "continuous", not "differentiable".

How should I continue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \geq y$ then observe that
$$xf(x)-yf(y) = x(f(x)- f(y)) + f(y)(x - y) \geq 0 $$ since $f$ is increasing. So $xf(x)$ is also increasing.

Now $$F^{''}(x) - F^{''}(y) = \int_{y}^{x} f(u) \, du + xf(x) - yf(y) > 0$$ since $f > 0$ and $xf(x)$ is increasing.

So we conclude that $F^{"}(x) $ is increasing.

Comment: Looks very nice! Thanks for help. Accepted.